# PHP - Having a "master php" which includes the needed html file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I want to have a index.php which includes the needed html file which is requested, but I have almost no experience with servers or PHP. I'm working on a webserver.

The code should look like this:

```
<?php

$requestedpage = ?;

switch($requestedpage)
{
case('courses'): include("html/courses.html"); 
break;

case('about'): include("html/aboutme.html");
break;

default: include("html/home.html");
break;

}

?>
```

but I don't know how to get the $requestedpage variable.
I do know the htaccess needs to be changed, it currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

But I don't know how.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I *think* you're looking for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define in `.htaccess` the `$_GET` variable.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?requestedpage=$1 [L]
```

Then, in your PHP, you need to get it.

```
$requestedpage = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'requestedpage');

switch (...) { ... }
```

So when you go to `localhost/project/courses` that translates to `localhost/project/index.php?requestedpage=courses` via `.htaccess`.

Comment: You've changed `requestedpage` to `requestedvariable` half way through your explanation. "that translates to `localhost/project/index.php?requestedpage=courses` via `.htaccess`." - assuming the `.htaccess` file is now in the `project` subdirectory.

Comment: @user82217 thanks, fixed it. and you're right. I assumed this was in a project directory, not the root.